# I tried to get the documents from cloud firestore but I am unable, due to "The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
addData(){
    Map<String, dynamic> Demodata = {"Name": "The growing developer",
    "motto":"Let's grow and learn together"
    };

    CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Patients');
    collectionReference.add(Demodata);
  }
```

```
  FectchData(){
    CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Patients');
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {

      List documents;
      setState(() {
        documents = snapshot.**documents**;<---- the word 'document' is uderlined 
                                                 by red color line
      });
    });
  }
```

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Create a new record"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: FectchData
                , child: Text(
                  "Patient details",
                )),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

            }, child: Text(
              "Contact Details",
            )),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

            }, child: Text(
              "Allergies/Adverse drug reaction",
            )),ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

            }, child: Text(
              "Immunisation Status",
            )),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
            Text(
              "Pregnancy details",
            )),

            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
            Text(
              "BreastFeeding details",
            )),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
            Text(
              "Social History details",
            )),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
            Text(
              "Past Medical History",
            )),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
            Text(
              "Medications and Supplements",
            )),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of documents from a snapshots() you need to call data docs

```dart
    snapshot.data.docs
```

be aware that you are not handling errors and connection state and your code is error-prone. You can read more in [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a `StreamBuilder` in order to handle the states of the stream much easier. You can try like this:

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: collectionReference.snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snashot.hasData) {
      // Do something...
    }
    var _documents = snapshot.data.docs;
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}
              , child: Text(
                "Patient details",
              )),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

          }, child: Text(
            "Contact Details",
          )),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

          }, child: Text(
            "Allergies/Adverse drug reaction",
          )),ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){

          }, child: Text(
            "Immunisation Status",
          )),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
          Text(
            "Pregnancy details",
          )),

          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
          Text(
            "BreastFeeding details",
          )),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
          Text(
            "Social History details",
          )),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
          Text(
            "Past Medical History",
          )),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child:
          Text(
            "Medications and Supplements",
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

About `StreamBuilder`: [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)